# Creative Common Public licence for Digg like site

Tags: creative-commons

What will be creative common public domain license for a digg like site.(social bookmarking site). Actually at the moment their old tool for public domain license  has expired.[There are more options in public domain license](http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/).Is that a right method for placing CC license for user content, or just place a Term of use document.

If a user shares links and videos on a site(just like a digg web site), What will be CC license that describes  copyright or no copyright at all.
Where should I put this question in stackexchange, if this is a not a right place.
 This website  explains about [digg website footer has link to CC0 license(creative common) but it is 2 years old and digg has removed the link.](http://www.labnol.org/internet/find-public-domain-content-with-creative-commons/8996/)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? You could give away any copyright rights you have. You could be trying to stop people making money out of what you do, you could be trying to stop people ripping you off without crediting you. I think we need more information as to what you want.

Comment: @paulmorriss , it's other people's content that I am talking about.e.g look at http://www.digg.com site.Users shares links/videos of other websites on digg.I have designed a system like digg but just I want to know whether I need any license for that or not or just place Term of Use document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If other people are giving you their content then you need a terms of use to say what you're going to do with it. As they are giving it voluntarily you can put what you like in those terms.

At one extreme you could say that they are assigning copyright to you and you can do what you like with it. At the other extreme you could say that when they give it to you you will put a CC0 license on it, so that you are giving away the copyright.

(I am not a lawyer though.)

Comment: thank you so much. I get it now. I have to put term of Use document.